# How do I implement breadcrumbs with complete links in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, breadcrumbs

I have managed to implement breadcrumbs in my vue.js application using npm.
But I'd like my breadcrumb to display a link to previous page, with the link to the current page(id included) next to it. Like this:

Home Page > Details page   (as clickeble links)

I've tried following the example from this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-2-breadcrumbs]

this is my index.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Details from '@/components/Details'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HomePage from '@/components/HomePage'
import VueBreadcrumbs from 'vue-2-breadcrumbs'

Vue.use(Router)
Vue.use(VueBreadcrumbs,{
template:
    '            <ul class="breadcrumb">\n' +
    '                <li v-for="(crumb, key) in $breadcrumbs" v-if="crumb.meta.breadcrumb" :key="key" class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">\n' +
    '                    <router-link :to="{ path: getPath(crumb) }">{{ getBreadcrumb(crumb.meta.breadcrumb) }}</router-link>' +
    '                </li>\n' +
    '            </ul>\n' 
})

export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: HomePage,
            name: 'HomePage',
            meta: {
                breadcrumb: 'Home Page',
            },

        },
        {
            path: '/Details/:id',
            component: Details,
            meta:{
                breadcrumb: function () {
                    const {name} = this.$route;
                    return `${name}`;
                  }
            },
            name: 'Details',
            props: true
        }


    ]
})
```

It all compiles, and it does render (but only one link, which is to the current page). Now I'd like to add the history link to my breadcrumb (the home page link). How do I do that?

Comment: Could you share a minimal pen? https://codepen.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I got some inspiration from all of your comments and this is how I fixed it:

So I added one extra `<li>` to hold the "home page" and the second `<li>` for looping over the current page... I also wrapped everything inside a root- so no errors about double root elements would occur.

```
Vue.use(VueBreadcrumbs,{
template:

'        <div v-if="$breadcrumbs.length" aria-label="breadcrumb">\n' +
'            <ol class="breadcrumb">\n' +
' <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>' +
'                <li v-for="(crumb, key) in $breadcrumbs" v-if="crumb.meta.breadcrumb" :key="key" class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">\n' +
'                    <router-link :to="{ path: getPath(crumb) }">{{ getBreadcrumb(crumb.meta.breadcrumb) }}</router-link>' +
'                </li>\n' +
'            </ol>\n' +
'        </div>'
})
```

Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add another router-link to your template:

```
<div id="root">
<router-link :to="/">Home</router-link>
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li v-for="(crumb, key) in $breadcrumbs" v-if="crumb.meta.breadcrumb" :key="key" class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
    <router-link :to="{ path: getPath(crumb) }">{{ getBreadcrumb(crumb.meta.breadcrumb) }}</router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
Declare your template in this way:

````
Vue.use(VueBreadcrumbs, {
  template: ```
    <div id="root">
    <router-link :to="/">Home</router-link>
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li v-for="(crumb, key) in $breadcrumbs" v-if="crumb.meta.breadcrumb" :key="key" class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
        <router-link :to="{ path: getPath(crumb) }">{{ getBreadcrumb(crumb.meta.breadcrumb) }}</router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  ```
})
````

Comment: ok, so I've tried this. And I get the error:" Error compiling template:

text "="/">" outside root element will be ignored."

Comment: specify your template inside triple backticks. Like this: Vue.use(VueBreadcrumbs, { template:``` <router-link :to="/">Home</router-link> ``` })

Comment: I did, but it gets a conflict since I can't have multiple root-elements

Comment: Add a div outside to have one root (put both the elements inside a div), as shown in the edited answer

Comment: Does it work by putting the html elements inside a div?

Comment: Ok, I've tried your last suggestion and I did get the same result as I had first. I still only have a link to the current page I'm at in my breadcrumb plus one text in the center of my page saying "="/">Home"

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Comment: No, need! Just managed to fix it. Got some inspiration from your previous suggestions and fixed it. Thank you ! (see other post for myt final solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own breadcrumb

In file 'index.ts' from router

```
export let activedRoutes: RouteRecord[] = []

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    activedRoutes = [];
    to.matched.forEach((record) => { activedRoutes.push(record) })
    next();
});
```

In route definition

```
{
        path: 'my-path-route',
        name: 'MyNameRoute',
        component: () => import('./MyComponent/MyComponent.component.vue'),
        meta: {
            title: 'Title',
            icon: 'my-icon',
            breadcrumb: { label: 'Label of bradcrumb', routeName: 'MyNameRoute'}
        },
}
```

Create a BreadbrumbComponent

```
    import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';
import { Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { activedRoutes } from '@/router';

@Component({})
export default class BreadcrumbsComponent extends Vue {

    breadcrumbs = []

    @Watch('$route')
    changeRoute() {
        this.breadcrumbs = activedRoutes.map(e => e.meta?.breadcrumb).filter(e => e);
    }

    created() {
        this.changeRoute()
    }

}
```

In html BreadcrumbComponent

```
    <template>
  <div class="breadcrumbs" v-if="breadcrumbs.length > 1">
    <ul class="v-breadcrumbs">
      <template v-for="(item, i) in breadcrumbs">
        <li :key="item.label">
          <router-link
            class="v-breadcrumbs__item"
            :to="{ name: item.routeName }"
            v-html="item.label"
            :class="{ disabled: breadcrumbs.length - 1 == i }"
          />
        </li>
        <li
          v-if="breadcrumbs.length - 1 > i"
          class="v-breadcrumbs__divider"
          :key="item.label"
        >
          <v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
        </li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

In scss of BreadcrumbComponent

```
    .breadcrumbs {
    .disabled {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
        cursor: default;
    }
}
```

Now is only use your component where wish

You can use the breadcrumb of vuetify to complement
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/breadcrumbs/#large